# Foundation make arrow switch with other class when off screen menu opens

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

So I've tried various javascript functions and toggle options to try and make the button switch from the right arrow to the left.

```
.arrow-right {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
  margin-left:10px;

}

.arrow-left {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid white;
transform:
```

The javascript I used to do this was

```
$('#showhide').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('arrow-left');
});
```

You can see the issue I'm running into in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bbarclay6/qbnc1jn7/7/

Any help is great and awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two classes. All you need to do is set the `transform` to `180deg` and `none` depending on the action:

```
//Rotate by 180 degrees when "showhide" is clicked i.e. when opening.
$('#showhide').click(function() {
  $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
});

//Remove the transform when the "exit-off-canvas is clicked i.e. when closing. 
$('.exit-off-canvas').click(function() {
  $('#showhide').css("transform", "none");
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/qbnc1jn7/22/)**